# How can I register an Angular2 Component whose DOM element has been created by another javascript library?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-components

Suppose I have some component `DynamicallyAddedComponent` associated with the selector `dynamically-added`. There is another component `ParentComponent` which contains some other, non-Angular, third party javascript which is manipulating its internal DOM tree and may add or remove `<dynamically-added>` tags.

When I add a `<dynamically-added>` tag directly to the template of `ParentComponent` it renders just fine, but when my third party library adds tags, angular does not recognize that a component has been added.

I have added both components to the `@NgModule` declarations in `app.module.ts`. I have also added calls to `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()` and `ApplicationRef.tick()` inside of  event handlers for the third party modification events.

So how do I manually tell Angular that a component has been added or removed?  How does Angular recognize and bootstrap components internally?

Comment: You can always use the `inspect` function of your web browser to see how DOM elements are `modified behind the scenes` and the `debug` option also allows you to `add breakpoints` so you can see the exact state of an element mid-script

Comment: @mike510a thanks for reminding me! I have used this before, but haven't used it in this instance. Unfortunately, the issue at hand involves DOM elements _not_ being modified when I'd like them to be, so there's no modifying behavior to debug. This is helpful advice though, and I'm sure it will be handy :)

Answer (score 1):

You could run the 3rd party event inside `ngZone` which would trigger `DOM` change detection.

Inside `component.ts`

```
constructor( public ngZone: NgZone) {}
ngZone.run( () => { // Change the property within the zone
  //3rd party event action
});
```

Comment: Raj-- thanks for the tip! In this instance, I'm dealing with a third party library which needs control over the position of elements I add (I'm trying to place ng2 components inside of a rich-text-editor, so yielding control over element placement to this app is non-negotiable).

What I can do is control the creation of the DOM node from within an 'element creation' callback of the 3rd party library. Will creating the node from within an ngZone execution environment help me here? When exactly does angular decide to pay attention to a DOM element?

Comment: add the creation instance inside ``ngZone.run``. try it out. ngZone would detect the changes happening inside it.